# How do I write a TCP app for AX22xx

Tags: c++, c, tcp

I am have brought a Development board AX22001. I want to write an TCP app server/client.

But I don't really know, where to write app and how to program it over.

Do anyone in here have got any experience with AX22001?

I hope you guys can help, I did try to write to AX22001 support but they are too slow answering my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know, there's a fairly comprehensive amount of information, demo code, manuals, APIs, and references on their website: http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=106;72;104. My suggestion would be to start reading through it!

Comment: First of all thx for answering. 

Well Landak ture that... 

But everytime I need a demo code file, I need to write to ASIX support and they are SLOW! But i will try that. I guess its my only way out. :)